# How to persist a block of objects in the database by using multithreading but in an order?

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate

I'm working with Hibernate, Maven project, and JBoss AS7. I have a select request which gives me a list of objects (let's say that I have for example 100000 clients) and I want to persist them in a new table. If I try to do that directly, then the JBoss server which I work with will gives me the famous error: `timeout`.

I'm considering if I can do this by using multithreading.

```
...
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
  for(Client client:ListClients{
    entityManager.persist(client);
   }
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
...
```

Comment: Have you considered persisting smaller chunks of data instead of introducing multithreading because of the timeout?

Comment: when i try to persist a lot of clients ( i don't khnow the number ) but in my database i have more than 25000000 clients so selecting and persisting that to an other table will take a lot of time and the server will  show the error message : timeout, that why i think that persist a block by block of clients will solve that issue.
Other think , i work too with native Query in same cases

Comment: If this is something that must be executed immediately and cannot be run as a batch at night, you should re-think your application's design. Of course I don't know your system, but maybe there is a way so you don't have to write so much data to a new table.

Comment: *in order* means *serial* which is the exact **opposite** of concurrent, so why do you want to use mutliple threads to then just make everything single threaded in *serial* again shows a fundamental lack of comprehension at best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multithreading is the wrong direction here, even more so if you want your inserts to happen in a particular order. You could process your entities in chunks of 1000 or so, committing each chunk separately, and either periodically flushing or using a stateless Hibernate session in order to keep the 1st level cache size down. The Hibernate documentation has a [chapter on batch processing](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/batch.html).

If this is data that's already in the database it may be a lot better to do this with a stored procedure or script that runs directly on the database. For importing data into a database check out what bulk copy tool comes with your database and use that instead. Bulk copy tools can temporarily drop database constraints and suspend rebuilding of indexes, and the network protocol is not chatty like JDBC, it will be a lot faster.